# How to program a button to change stylesheets with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please note that I am not using classes.  I haven't found an answer for this SPECIFIC question.

Using javascript, how can I program a button to change the stylesheet each time the button is clicked?

I've tried different if, else if and else, but when I try them, it breaks the code (ie, it will change the color to blue if red, but not back again).
It works with 2 buttons, but getting it to change each time a single button is clicked seems to be eluding me.  I got feed up and programmed a second button to change it back.

This works for 2 buttons:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>"Your Title Here"</title>
    <link id="um" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet1.css">
        <style>
        </style>

</head>

<body>
<p>booga</p>
<button id="x" onclick="myFunction()">blue</button>
<button id="x1" onclick="myFunction1()">red</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
if (document.getElementById("um").href = "stylesheet1.css"){
document.getElementById("um").href = "stylesheet2.css"} 
}
function myFunction1() {
if (document.getElementById("um").href = "stylesheet2.css"){
document.getElementById("um").href = "stylesheet1.css"} 
}
</script>
</body>
```

I would like to be able to get rid of the second button and second function and have it all with one button.

EDIT...
I tried this, and it failed.

```
    function myFunction() {
if (document.getElementById("um").href == "stylesheet1.css")
{document.getElementById("um").href = "stylesheet2.css"}; 
else {document.getElementById("um").href = "stylesheet1.css"} 
}
```

Comment: @Typo: Mmm, no it’s not.

Comment: How does a new programmer get any rep on this site when somebody always says "Oh, that's a duplicate!  Down with you!"

Comment: @Bugiroff be patient, things takes time. you got any way my up vote

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're using == instead of = for your comparisons!

```
if (document.getElementById("um").href == "stylesheet1.css")
```

etc

Comment: doesn't solve whole problem... href property will be absolute url, not same as attribute value

Comment: so more along the lines of:        function myFunction() {
 if (document.getElementById("um").href == "stylesheet1.css")
 {document.getElementById("um").href = "stylesheet2.css"}; 
 else {document.getElementById("um").href = "stylesheet1.css"} 
 }

Comment: To just check for the stylesheet name, you should be able to use if(document.getElementById("um").href.indexOf("stylesheet1") > -1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button id="x" onclick="myFunction()">Change</button>

<script>

    function myFunction() {
      var link = document.getElementById("um");
      var segments = link.href.split('/');
      var currentStyle = segments[segments.length - 1];
      var style =  (currentStyle == 'stylesheet1.css') ? 'stylesheet2' 
                                                       : 'stylesheet1';
      document.getElementById("um").href = style + ".css"
    }

</script>
```

Comment: In my case console.log(document.getElementById("um").href) returns file:///C:/Users/aespiritu/Desktop/aloha/stylesheet1.css

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>"Your Title Here"</title>
    <link id="um" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet1.css">

</head>

<body>
<p>booga</p>
<button onclick="myFunction('um','stylesheet1.css', 'stylesheet2.css')">swap</button>

<script>
function myFunction(id,a,b) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    var hrefStr;
    if(~el.href.indexOf(a)) {
        hrefStr = el.href.replace(a, b);
        el.href = hrefStr;
    } else {
        hrefStr = el.href.replace(b, a);
        el.href = hrefStr;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```